# Want to listen to ALL my Compact Discs via iPad

Tags: ipad, music

Ok, here goes!

I’m an old guy with limited computer skills but lots of music that I like listening to on my home stereo system. This is what I would like to do:

I love my iPad Air 3. It’s all I got computer wise and over 300 hard earned purchased CDs. I want to listen to all this music via my iPad. Touch something on the screen and it plays the music I have OFFLINE.

I know I will need a computer/laptop, an external dvd player, and an external storage device. Everything else I read that I might need is quite confusing to me. Don’t use iTunes, need this storage device, use this player, and onwards.

TMI for me! I don’t want to stream. Just listen to what I have. Willing to pick up a apple laptop to hopefully make all this easier.

Simple solutions would be best for me. Any suggestions for us newbies? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5):

What you *really* need is iTunes [or the newer Apple Music, but that won't actually help… read on…].
The reason you need iTunes is that's the only way to get the music onto the iPad. The iPad can't play the actual CDs, of course.

So, you want an *old* Mac (or a PC, but hey, we're all Mac fans here ;) one with a CD/DVD drive. This is going to be maybe 10 years old or so (& therefore *cheap*;). Modern ones don't have optical drives any more, though you can get external ones… maybe too much faff if all you want is a machine to enable your transfers.

Older Macs still use iTunes [that's why you don't need to care about Apple Music which replaced iTunes]

Once you run iTunes, you can feed it CDs one at a time & bring them all into iTunes.
Your Mac will need to be able to see an internet connection whilst it's doing this, to get the album & track titles & the artwork. [These are not on the CD at all, it uses some smart recognition software to 'guess' what the album is.]
You can then sync these to your iPad & carry your entire CD collection wherever you go.

I found a pictorial guide to the actual process - they used a PC but the method is the same - https://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-import-cd-tracks-to-itunes/

As a bonus - the Mac will also now contain all your CDs, giving you two means of playback.

*Note: This is all a bit complex to run the entire procedure in a few paragraphs. If you need further detail as you work through it, it may well be worth asking additional, more focussed questions.*

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. Willing to get a new apple laptop if in the end I only mostly use my iPad to access all my tunes. Do I need a NAS? Or an additional external storage device? Over 300 cds not going to fit on a new air laptop? Everyone seems to hate Apple Music, what alternative easy software can I get?

Comment: @raykazlauskas If you use the default 128kbps Apple AAC encoding, that's about 1 MB / minute. 300 CDs * 70 minutes * 1 MB / min ≈ 21 GB. So that can definitely fit. Even if you use the fancy 256 kbps AAC encoding, it'll still fit.

Comment: The 'advantages', in this case of a older Mac is a) the built-in DVD drive & b) only iTunes, no Apple Music [you're offered a subscription but you can ignore it & just use it like it always was.] iTunes was what drove Apple's success in the 2000's, a billion iPods freed the world of cassette Walkmans & portable CD players. All your music collection in one tiny box. Your iPad can just be a bigger version of this box. A Macbook Pro 13" 2012 was the last to have the optical drive; running Mojave it would be technically out of date, but not too old to use. I've seen them on eBay at £120.

Comment: Thx for everyone’s support. I’m iffy on old tech so I’ll probably get a new Mac air, a fat ssd, and an external burner. Besides iTunes, what 3rd party non streaming music player should I get? Thank again.

Comment: I'd go with 'old tech'. You want this for one task, then you're done with it. iTunes [now called Music] is already on the iPad waiting to go, once you sync your ripped CDs to it. A 2012 Mac with Mojave is not from pre-history, it's still a perfectly usable structure for a year or three - more if you're not interested in the 'new shiny' every year. It's a no-brainer [& cheap], really. I've set up my octogenarian parents with this type of setup & they're happy as Larry. [certainly compared to 15 years of prior bi-weekly remote accessing the bl@@dy PC they used to use ;)

Comment: Interesting. Makes my head scratch. Always want to save money. Would 2012 tech be dependable enough to hold my collection? Remember, this is off-line. Will not have or want on-line access after I’ve done the digital dump. Would a NAS be a good investment?Thank you again for your thoughts.

Comment: The almost unique position of the 2012 was that not only was it the last with a DVD drive, it was also the last with replaceable batteries & hard drive - making it much more robust over time than anything newer, the two most likely to fail components are renewable.  You could ensure data-retention by plugging an external hard drive into the Mac & letting Time Machine take care of it all. A NAS is an unnecessary [& difficult to manage] complication by comparison.

Comment: Great discussion. Thanks for playing. Some more questions. I understand the value of the internal DVD drive, but in upgrading this laptop I understand stand it would be best to replace said drive with a newer one with more memory capacity. I do this AFTER I rip all my cd? Also thinking about using MusicStreamer to access my music files via my iPad. Makes sense to you? Again, much thanks for your help.

Comment: You're over-complicating things. Upgrading the storage *after* you've done all this without losing everything is not trivial & would need the external Time Machine to be already set up perfectly. Running a streaming app after you've already synced to the iPad is fairly pointless, it's all already there.